# Playing audio file into the call android

Tags: android, call

Say I make a call to someone with my android phone.
Is it possible to play some audio file into the call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stream audio to a phone call Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried like this

```
if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
      AudioManager am = (AudioManager) pccontext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
      am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); 
      am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(pccontext, R.raw.beep);
      mp.start();
}
```

But its not working in `MODE_NORMAL`. When I tried with `MODE_IN_CALL` phone is playing the audio but caller on the other side is not able to listen the audio played by the receiver phone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible,  it is an Android security limitation.