# Play a sound file in phonecall android

Tags: android, mp3, microphone

I want to ask you if there is an API that plays a sound file (mp3,...) instead of microphone or change the input from microphone to speaker like stereo mix on windows .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stream audio to a phone call Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this question:

[Stream audio to a phone call Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android)

Summary: You need to be rooted if you want to achieve that