# Send recorded audio as microphone input to Gboard

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, gboard

A similar, but different question was asked here: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629330/send-recorded-audio-as-microphone-input),
in that case they wanted to send audio to a phone call.

I am curious about a different situation.

I want to send audio from an application to the Gboard when it is being used with my application, in order to get local speech recognition done. [link2](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19371890)

Is it possible to send audio from my app into Gboard such that it uses the local speech recognizer?

Using the Android Pixel audio APIs?

Using some direct APIs to Gboard?

Comment: Did you ever find a way?