Android custom device AUDIO HAL
I am trying to build a custom FrankenPhone. I got stuck trying to make it use new device audio device for call. I can initiate it using terminal commands to forward output of one command to the input of another so that my microphone is forwarded to the GSM modem so the person on the other side of the line can hear me.
But I don't understand why I need to run this command. Why doesn't android do this by default? Or what needs to happen so that it does it by default?
seems to be related to ./packages/services/Telecomm/src/com/android/server/telecom/CallAudioModeStateMachine.java
or     ./frameworks/av/services/audiopolicy/engineconfigurable/config/example/phone/audio_policy_engine_product_strategies.xml`
I got a development board, attached a screen, added GSM modem.
I built the source code that broadband provider sent. All parts seem to work separately. My GSM modem becomes another audio device. I initiate calls, I can record voice and send voice using commands.
here is reference to what I have done, these are threads I opened. As you can see I could not get much support on call-audio one. May be somebody can lead me in the right direction I bought myself a google pixel phone hoping to run working code on it and compare to mine.
https://forum.radxa.com/t/radxa-phone-rock5b-call-audio/15730/10
https://forum.radxa.com/t/mipi-10-screen-with-android/14202/11
https://forum.radxa.com/t/radxa-phone-with-cellular-module/13181/34

this seems to be related
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android?rq=4

This question is similar to: Stream audio to a phone call Android. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Upon checking I see that one is for app level. I am working on system level.
